# Force showing the browser's HTTP authentication dialog

Tags: ajax, rest, http, authentication, http-authentication

There are already several questions that ask for suppressing the browser's HTTP authentication dialog, and they seem to suggest that this dialog automatically appears when the response code is `401` and the `WWW-Authenticate` header is present in a response.

I'm building a web application that calls a RESTful API using Ajax, which is protected with basic HTTP authentication. I'm working on both the web app and the API.

The default behaviour is to, when authentication is required but not present, simply give an error

```
{"error":"Authentication required"}
```

with a `404` status. However, I would like to create one endpoint, `/user/login`, which returns the `401` code and a `WWW-Authenticate` header when there is no valid `Authorization` header present in the request. I know this isn't exactly RESTful, but it should work.

I have now implemented this and when I open the endpoint in my browser it works fine: the browser's dialog shows. However, when I request the endpoint using Ajax, no dialog is shown (both Chromium and Firefox).

**How do I force showing this dialog with an Ajax request, if at all possible?**

The exact response is now:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-url
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 12:21:10 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Please login"

Please login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "Login" web page that requires basic auth and link to it. It can have a meta or JavaScript redirect back to your main application; the redirect will only be applied after the user has authenticated themselves.

You could alternatively just request username and password using JavaScript and send them with subsequent Ajax calls (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613117/18706).

Comment: I went with the second approach, but didn't want to store the username and password locally for security reasons. So, I implemented a token endpoint in the API which requires a password. The token is valid for some time, can be used to login, and can be stored locally in a cookie. The user has the possibility to link tokens to his IP. For important actions, such as changing email address and password, I still require password authentication (similar to GitHub's sudo mode), so that cookie stealing is no big issue. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yes, a token exchange makes sense for improved security.

Answer (score 0):

As a (temporary?) workaround, I'm now redirecting users to the API, which I give a `redirect` parameter to which the user is redirected back when authentication has succeeded.